# jQuery toggle show/hide default content

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I have a show/hide toggle that switches between content if menu `a` is clicked.

Before the click function is triggered content is shown in the `default` div.

For some reason if you click one of the `a` tag's twice it successfully toggles the content on/off; **however you are left with a blank screen**

This is a poor user experience.

**How can I avoid this and ensure that the default content is shown if a user selects a menu item twice?**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $show = $('.show');

  $('.menu a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $show.not(this).stop().hide(450);
    $($(this).attr('href')).stop().toggle(450);
    $('.default').addClass('hidden');
  });


});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="#show-screen">Screen</a>
  <a href="#show-music">Music</a>
  <a href="#show-art">Art</a>
  <a href="#show-food">Food</a>
</div>

<div id="show-screen" class="show">show screen</div>
<div id="show-music" class="show">show music</div>
<div id="show-art" class="show">show art</div>
<div id="show-food" class="show">show food</div>

<div class="default">default content</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to hide if shown and clicked again ?

Comment: @pc_coder Yes, so if I complete the action of show/hide by clicking twice - I want the default `div` to be visible. As opposed to a blank screen

Comment: var atLeastOneElemtVisible = false, divs = $('.show');
divs.forEach(elem=>{
    if(!elem.style.visiblity('hidden')){ // correct the syntax
        atLeastOneElemtVisible = true;
        break;
    }
});
if(!atLeastOneElemtVisible){
  $('.default').removeClass('hidden');  
}

Comment: @RahulDwivedi can you add that code as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Sure Just did that. Basically this is the idea: Check if all the `show` divs are hidden. If Yes, remove the `hidden` class from your `default` div. Please excuse me for any syntactical error.

Comment: Would be good if you had a codepen or JSFiddle to show it working - I can't vote your answer

Comment: hmm let me create one.

Comment: @JordanMiguel here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/6cnt95ap/ Apologies for the delay. It's been a while and I had forgot JQuery. Had trouble correcting the syntax :)

Comment: @RahulDwivedi Sorry I'm afraid that doesn't work. Thanks for tyring to help.

Comment: @JordanMiguel My bad. There ware a couple of mistakes in that. Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/6cnt95ap/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'd suggest a completely different approach to handle this problem, to make your code work, I'd do something like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/6cnt95ap/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $show = $('.show');
  $('.menu a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $show.not(this).stop().hide(450);
    $($(this).attr('href')).stop().toggle(450);
    $('.default').addClass('hidden');

  window.setTimeout(()=>{
        var showDefault = true, divs = $('.show');
     divs.each(function(){
       if($(this).css("display") !=='none'){
            showDefault = false;
            return false;
          }
    });
    if(showDefault){
          $('.default').removeClass('hidden');  
     }
  }, 500)

    });


  })
```

Comment: Excellent - this does the job. Do you mind briefly explaining what it being done - so I can know what is happening. Many thanks!

Comment: Basically what I have done is this: iterate though each of the divs to find their ‘display’ property and if any of them are found to be visible, showDefault is set to false, I.e we won’t be showing the default text in this case. Finally wrap it up inside window.setTimeout with 500 milliseconds (>=450 that you have used) this is necessary in order to make sure the earlier effects take place and after that only this happens.

Comment: I just realised if I click 'screen' it shows default content. If I click screen again it shows me the screen content. It seems like the function is working in the wrong order

Comment: @JordanMiguel Initially, whenever there was a block screen, now 'default content' will be shown which is what your issue was, if I interpret correctly.